# Facebook open graph action to a friend with an object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post message with message_tags field using Graph API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351194/how-to-post-message-with-message-tags-field-using-graph-api-in-php)
>   [Can I post on a friends' wall as “Open Graph Action” or I need a classic “wall post”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661667/can-i-post-on-a-friends-wall-as-open-graph-action-or-i-need-a-classic-wall-p)

I am trying to do an action to a friend with an object, Lets say I want to do

"Jon Doe" sent an "item" to "Merry Smith" via "My Cool App"

where "sent" is the "Action"
"item" is the "object"
"Merry Smith" is Jon's friend on FB.
"My Cool App" is my app.

with open graph I was only able to get

"Jon doe" sent an "item" -with "Merry Smith" via "My Cool App"  or able to just "Tag" in a message.